# How to make python subprocesses run faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm using a subprocess to get the output of a command, running the command normally takes about 2 1/2 minutes but when ran using subprocess it takes around 35 minutes.

This is the code in question:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["wpscan --url " + s + " –e u"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = process.communicate()[0]
```

Is there anyway to make it run faster? I'm not super familiar with using subprocess just yet, so I may need an explanation.

Comment: this is **the** classical example of where you shouldn't use `Popen(..., shell=True)`. Using the default `shell=False` is not only simpler, but also safe!

Comment: however, your Python code is not at all involved with what your spawned process does, so you can't solve this (unless, actually my advise above leads to your shell not doing something unexpected with an `s` that contains for example the substring ` & sleep 2000`, and `&`  and `;` are rather common in URLs, so my guess is, `shell=True` is your enemy here)

Comment: Thanks! and yeah I made sure it only had regular characters in it, so it's definitely the shell=True. I'll try it!

Comment: As to the issue raised by @MarcusMüller, you may want to encode your URL with ```safe_s = urllib.parse.quote_plus(s)```

Comment: @user23952 that's usually counterproductive - URL encoding is necessary for HTTP requests, not something a program expects in its arguments; then again, don't know what `wpscan` even is.

Comment: @MarcusMüller From Google it's a security scanner for a WordPress website. I guess it checks whether the site has been patched against known WordPress vulnerabilities.

Comment: @MarcusMüller maybe you have a better understanding of the ```subprocess``` implementation, but what happens if the URL contains parts that can be interpreted as shell commands? For example ```s='http://www.cnn.com? &'```?

Comment: then they will be interpreted by the shell. That's the whole point of using the shell (`shell=True`). If you just want to pass the value `http://www.cnn.com? &` as an argument to an executable, you'd simply use `shell=False` and `Popen(["wpscan", "--url", s, "-e", "u"])`

Comment: Then I agree, ```shell=False``` is simpler and safer :)

Comment: Don't answer in the comments, people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in particular about `subprocess` that makes the spawned process behave slower/differently.

The difference in behavior is almost certainly due to how your arguments are being interpreted. When you provide command in list form, each list item should be a part of the command. You should leverage that instead of trying to create the command components by string concatenation

For example:

```
# good
flag_arg = 'Foo' 
subprocess.Popen(['command', '--flag', flag_arg])
#bad
subprocess.Popen(['command --flag' + flag_arg])
```

The `shell=True` is also unnecessary. What you should need is something like this:

```
Popen(["wpscan", "--url", s, "-e", "u"])
```